# Validation not working after clear the form

Tags: angular, validation, bootstrap-4, angular-reactive-forms

I am unable to clear using this.stockForm.reset(); so I am using this for clear the data after submit:

```
 clearall(): void {
        this.isEditMode = false;
        this.stockForm.reset({
            sku: '',
            productName: '',
            counted: '',
        });
        Object.keys(this.stockForm.controls).forEach(key => {
            this.stockForm.get(key).setErrors(null);
        });
}
```

When I click on submit button again I'm unable to get validation; getting default values; so let me know how to again validate after clearing the form.

Comment: Why can't you use the `reset()` function on your form?

Comment: You should be able to use this.stockForm.reset() function which is available in typescript.

Comment: @ng-suhas while using that showing touched error on form fields

Comment: do you have stackblitz for this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just rest your form like that:

```
 clearall(): void {
        this.isEditMode = false;
        this.stockForm.reset();
        Object.keys(this.stockForm.controls).forEach(key => {
            this.stockForm.get(key).setErrors(null);
        });
     }
```

Comment: above working fine but again im click on submit button need to show validations but its not happening ?

Comment: why are you setError(null)?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using Validators.required while resetting the form?

```
clearall(): void {
        this.isEditMode = false;
        this.stockForm.reset({
            sku: ['', Validators.required],
            productName: ['', Validators.required],
            counted: ['', Validators.required],
        });
        Object.keys(this.stockForm.controls).forEach(key => {
            this.stockForm.get(key).setErrors(null);
        });
}
```

Hope it helps!Cheers!

Please check this example => https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-lgguij

Comment: i written same thing above but while reclick on submit button validations not working

Comment: Can you please mention the initial formGroup before resetting the form?

Answer (score 0):

After resetting the form you are running validations manually by calling setErrors(null).
setErrors(null) means you are setting the form property as valid so you will not get any validation message.

[setErrors](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#seterrors)

It will be working once you have removed the below code

```
 Object.keys(this.stockForm.controls).forEach(key => {
        this.stockForm.get(key).setErrors(null);
    });
```